# How to print first row of a file as a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv

I need to grab the first row of a .csv file (the headers), and return it as a list.

I tried something like this:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

But it prints the entire csv file. I was also thinking of just breaking the for loop immediately after printing the first row, but I didn't think that was the most efficient way to do it.

Is there a better way?

Comment: just add `break` after the `print`

Comment: using `reader[0]`, `reader[1]` ...

Answer (score 1):

Since [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) object upports the [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) protocol you can simply call the `next` function on it to get the first item :

```
reader = csv.reader(f)
print next(reader)
```